# 2 Bootstrap Datepickers: How to change min and max dates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have 2 datepickers on my webpage: One for the arrival date and the other for departure.

Now I'd like to set the min and max dates, according to the user selection.

2 Examples of what I want to achieve:

1. User selects 29.03.2015 as arrival -> departure's min date is set
   accordingly.
2. User selects 29.03.2015 as departure -> arrival's max
   date is set accordingly.

At the moment I am initializing the datepickers like so:

```
        var startDate = "<?php echo date('d.m.Y'); ?>"; // Today
        $('#startDate.input-group.date').datepicker({
            format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
            language: "de",
            multidate: false,
            todayHighlight: true,
            startDate: startDate,
            weekStart: 1
        }).on('changeDate', function(e){ 
            changeDate(e);
        });
        $('#endDate.input-group.date').datepicker({
            format: "dd.mm.yyyy",
            language: "de",
            multidate: false,
            todayHighlight: true,
            startDate: startDate,
            weekStart: 1
        });
```

You notice the .on() function on the first datepicker. This is my current attempt to set the date of the 2nd one:

```
        function changeDate(e){
            $('#endDate.input-group.date').datepicker('setStartDate', e);
        }
```

However this leaves me with the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function: bootstrap-datepicker.js:1493

The line in question is this:

```
parts = date.match(/([\-+]\d+)([dmwy])/g)
```

Can you please give me a hint on what I am doing wrong and on how I can achieve said effect?

Comment: Is it possible the parameter, `e`, isn't valid? I would check what its value is when you pass it into `changeDate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you console.log changing like this:

```
.on('changeDate', function(e){ 
        console.log(e);
});
```

you'll see the event returns an event object;
you should try passing something like e.date (but be sure to format the string accordingly to your startDate format).

Here's more about the extra data attached to the event object : http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html